# How do you invalidate a form submit on a piece in Apostrophe CMS?

Tags: apostrophe-cms

I am trying to send an SNS on the form submit on a custom piece I have created, if the SNS publish fails I want to stop the save process. But I can't find any information about how to invalidate the form and stop the save process.

I am using the beforeSave hook. Using apos.notify() to set an error message. But I can't find anyway to stop the save if I get an error back from the SNS publish.

Please can someone give me some pointers here.

Comment: Did one of these answers help?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can cancel a save from within `beforeSave` .. it's just a method called before saving to give you a chance to modify data or talk to APIs etc.

What you probably want to do is have your form submit to a custom route that does the validation. If the validation fails, send it back to the browser. If it succeeds, create a new instance of the piece, populate it with your content, and `insert` it.

### Sketch

**A form on some page**

```
<form>
  <label for="title">Record Title</label>
  <input type="text" name="title" id="title"><br />
  <label for="artist">Artist</label>
  <input type="text" name="artist" id="artist">
  <input data-submit type="submit">
</form>
```

**some front-end javascript listening for form submission (use whatever technology you like)**

```
$(function() {
  var $submit = $('[data-submit]');
  var $form = $('form');

  $submit.on('click', submit);

  function submit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
      method: 'POST',
      data: $form.serialize(),
      url: '/modules/records/submit',
    })
    .done(function( data ) {
      console.log(data);
    });
  }
});
```

**A route and handling of the form submission, this example uses a pieces module called `records`, the file would be located in `/lib/modules/records/index.js`**

```
module.exports = {        
  name: 'record',        
  extend: 'apostrophe-pieces',        
  label: 'Record',
  pluralLabel: 'Records',
  afterConstruct: function (self) {
    self.route('post', 'submit', async function (req, res) {
      try {

        // req.body is your form as object
        // validate as you want

        if (req.body.artist && req.body.title) {

          // the exisitence of our properties is enough for us
          // let's work on inserting them as a piece

          // if your in a foreign module
          //const piece = self.apos.docs.getManager('PIECE-TYPE').newInstance();

          const piece = self.newInstance();

          piece.title = req.body.title;
          piece.artist = req.body.artist;

          // if your in a foreign module
          //
          // await self.apos.modules['MODULE-NAME'].insert(req, piece);
          //

          await self.insert(req, piece);

          // if your submitting from a place where the user doesn't have permissions
          // but you trust them anyway (like if they are logged out of Apostrophe)
          //
          // await self.insert(req, piece, { permissions: false });
          //

          self.apos.notify(req, 'all good', { type: 'success' });
          return res.json({ status: 'success' })
        } else {
          self.apos.notify(req, 'something went wrong', { type: 'error' });
          return res.json({ status: 'error' })
        }
      } catch (error) {
        return self.apos.utils.error(error);
      }
    });
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Here I'm going to make a different assumption: that you're talking about a logged-in user inserting or editing a piece via our UI. I think that is likely because `apos.notify` is only useful when you have a logged-in user.

In that case, you can report an error to the callback of `beforeSave` like this:

```
self.beforeSave = function(req, piece, options, callback) {
  if (badThingHappens) {
    self.apos.notify(req, 'A bad thing happened.', { type: 'error' });
    return callback('SNS');
  }
  // All is well
  return callback(null);
};
```

This gets it done with very little code, but the user will get two error messages. A generic one, and your notification.

With a little more effort we can class this up by recognizing the "SNS" error on the browser side and treating it specially:

```
// in lib/modules/my-pieces-module/public/js/editor-modal.js
apos.define('my-pieces-module-editor-modal', {
  extend: 'apostrophe-pieces-editor-modal',
  construct: function(self, options) {
    self.getErrorMessage = function(err) {
      if (err === 'SNS') {
        return 'An SNS error occurred saving the item.';
      } else {
        return 'An error occurred saving the item.';
      }
    };
  }
});
```

Now we can remove the `apos.notify` call on the server side because the one and only error message is more relevant to our needs.

Note that the actual error is only sent to the browser if it is a string. If it is an Error object it is logged on the server but not send to the browser, for security reasons. This way you can decide whether an error is something the user has any business knowing the details of or not.